# Права доступа Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Необходимо создать пользователя на bitbucket, который бы имел доступ на чтение только основной ветки - master, причем видел бы только выбранные мною коммиты либо tags.

Comment: В Вашем тексте нет даже знака вопроса. Что у Вас не получается?

Comment: то что я и написал, не получается

Comment: [Вот](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html), близкое к теме.

Comment: ситуация такая, клиент хочет видеть репозиторий. Можно ли все рабочие ветки скрыть, оставить только мастер с определенными коммитами?

Comment: Едва ли. Чаще всего в таких сервисах можно предоставить одну или несколько веток, но не отдельные коммиты.

Comment: Из документации, что Вы мне дали, я понял лишь одно, что можно запретить редактирование веток и оставить только для чтения, но насчет самой видимости для отдельных пользователей ничего не сказано.